# Intro programming: Conways Game of Life

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

I have been working on this code for a long time and i can't seem to figure it out. The top portion of my code works to pre-populate the grid. but for some reason I cant get my image to move and to grow as its supposed to. Please Help Me!!

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Life {
    public static void main(String []args){

        //Declaring and initializing grid variables
        int gridSize = 200;
        int cellSize = 3;
        Grid grid = new Grid(gridSize, cellSize, "The Game of Life");
        grid.setDelay(10);

        Random r = new Random();
        int aliveColor = 1;
        int deadColor= 0;
        int aliveCells;
        int row = 0; 
        int column =  0;
        int val = grid.getPos(row,column);
        int generation;
        int aliveNeighbors;
        int cell;

        //loop statement pre-populating the grid
        for (row = 0; row <= gridSize-1; row++){
            for(column = 0; column <= gridSize-1; column++){
                if (r.nextInt(100) > 49){
                    grid.setPos(row,  column, aliveColor);
                }
                else
                    grid.setPos(row, column, deadColor);
            }
        }
        grid.initialize();


        //Loop executing the rules of the Game of Life
        do
        {
            row = 0;
            column = 0;
            generation = 0;
            while (row <= gridSize-1){
                while (column <= gridSize-1){
                    cell = grid.getPos(row, column);
                    aliveNeighbors = grid.matchingNeighbors(row, column,aliveColor);
                    if (cell == aliveColor)
                    {
                        if (aliveNeighbors == 2 || aliveNeighbors == 3){
                            val =1;
                            grid.setPos(row,  column,val);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (cell == deadColor)
                    {   
                        if (aliveNeighbors == 3){
                            val =1;
                            grid.setPos(row, column,val);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        val = 0;
                        grid.setPos(row,column,val);

                    }
                    column++;
                }   
                row++;
                grid.update();
            } 
            grid.update();
            generation++;
        } while (generation >= 0);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
//Loop executing the rules of the Game of Life

    do
    {   
        row = 0;
        column = 0;
        generation = 0;
        while (row <= gridSize-1){
            while (column <= gridSize-1){
                cell = grid.getPos(row, column);
                aliveNeighbors = grid.matchingNeighbors(row, column,aliveColor);
                if (cell == aliveColor)
                {
                    if (aliveNeighbors == 2 || aliveNeighbors == 3){
                        val =1;
                        grid.setPos(row,  column,val);
                    }
                    if (aliveNeighbors ==1 || aliveNeighbors == 4){
                        val = 0;
                        grid.setPos(row,column,val);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (cell == deadColor)
                    {   
                        if (aliveNeighbors == 3){
                            val =1;
                            grid.setPos(row, column,val);
                        }
                        if (aliveNeighbors == 1 || aliveNeighbors == 2 || aliveNeighbors == 4){
                            val = 0;
                            grid.setPos(row, column, val);
                        }
                    }
                }   
                column++;
            }
            row++;
        } 
        grid.update();
        generation++;
    } while (generation >= 0);
}








    EDIT****
      do
    {   
        row = 0;
        column = 0;
        generation = 0;
        while (row <= gridSize-1){
            while (column <= gridSize-1){
                cell = grid.getPos(row, column);
                aliveNeighbors = grid.matchingNeighbors(row, column,aliveColor);
                if (cell == aliveColor)
                {
                    if (aliveNeighbors == 2 || aliveNeighbors == 3){
                        grid.setPos(row, column, aliveColor);
                    } else {
                        grid.setPos(row,column, deadColor); 
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (cell == deadColor){ 
                        if (aliveNeighbors == 3){
                            grid.setPos(row, column,aliveColor);
                        } else {
                            grid.setPos(row,column,deadColor);
                        }
                    }
                }   
                column++;
            }
            row++;
        } 
        grid.update();
        generation++;
    } while (generation >= 0);
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without the `Grid` class.

Comment: I think we are only supposed to use one grid. And we added a jar file into eclipse in order to access the grid. Here is a link to the directions.http://cobweb.cs.uga.edu/~cs1301/files/Lab07.pdf

Comment: Ah. Look at rules 14 and 15, then look back at your code's loop.

Comment: Ive moved the gridupdate(); around a lot but it never makes a difference. I deleted the one after row++ so that is matches the rules but it still doesnt work. is my understanding incorrect? Im sorry that Im asking so many questions i just really want to get this done because its due tonight and ive been working on it for the past 4 days :(

Comment: What actually happens when your program starts running the game? Does it crash? Is there an error message? Is it just not working right? What is it doing?

Comment: No, the program runs as an infinite loop, but I receive a still black and white image. The pattern of the image is supposed to move and evolve. Thats how I know that at least the beginning of my code works. its the final loop that is the issue

Comment: Expanded my answer to respond to your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems that I have noticed:

1. You should only update the grid after you complete updating all the cells.
2. Your indentation was off, and there was a `}` misplaced. After re-formatting, it can clearly be seen that you are not covering all the cases, so there are cells that do not get a new value. For example, if a cell is alive, you only handle the case when it has 2 or 3 neighbors, but there is no `else` to that `if`, and so, a live cell with 1 or 4 or more neighbors is never updated.

   You may think that somehow in that case the code falls through to the general "else", but in fact, it never gets there. All cell values are either "alive" or "dead". So a construct such as:

   ```
   if ( cell == aliveColor ) {
       // Handle alive cell
   } else if ( cell == deadColor ) {
       // Handle dead cell
   } else {
       // Handle all other cases - but there are none!
   }
   ```

   Is equivalent to:

   ```
   if ( cell == aliveColor ) {
      // Handle alive cell
   } else {
      // Handle dead cell
   }
   ```

   The original "else" is never reached because there is no other case than "aliveColor" and "deadColor".

---

**Response to your edit:**

```
            if (cell == aliveColor)
            {
                if (aliveNeighbors == 2 || aliveNeighbors == 3){
                    val =1;
                    grid.setPos(row,  column,val);
                }
                if (aliveNeighbors ==1 || aliveNeighbors == 4){
                    val = 0;
                    grid.setPos(row,column,val);
                }
            }
```

For some reason, you seem to think that there could be at most 4 neighbors to each cell. Look at the example cell in your lab document again:

```
⬜︎⬜︎⬛︎
⬛︎⬜︎⬛︎
⬛︎⬛︎⬜︎
```

This cell has **5** dead neighbors, and 3 live ones. In fact, each cell can have up to 8 neighbors - the diagonal neighbors also count!

But your rules were:

> 1. If x is alive and has exactly 2 or 3 live neighbors, then x survives to the next generation. Otherwise it dies.
> 2. If x is dead and has exactly 3 live neighbors, then x is alive in the next generation. Otherwise it remains dead

This *otherwise* translates directly to `else` in programming. So instead of having a second `if` with the complementary condition (if there are 1, 4,5,6,7 or 8 live neighbors...), just give the first if an `else`:

```
                if (aliveNeighbors == 2 || aliveNeighbors == 3) {
                    grid.setPos(row, column, aliveColor);
                } else {
                    grid.setPos(row, column, deadColor);
                }
```

The same thing applies to the rules for a dead cell, of course.

(Note that I also removed the `val=1` and just used the value directly, `val` is superfluous. Also I used the names that explain what the value is rather than 1 and 0 (what if you want to change the game to work with green and red)?).

---

One important thing that I didn't notice before:

```
do
{   
    row = 0;
    column = 0;
    generation = 0;
    while (row <= gridSize-1){
        while (column <= gridSize-1){
```

You initialize both the row and the column to zero before the *row* loop.

This means that at the end of the first row, `column` stays `gridSize-1` and is not set to zero again. So in fact you are only updating one row and then only the last column of each of the other rows.

It should be:

```
  do
{   
    row = 0;
    generation = 0;
    while (row <= gridSize-1){
        column = 0;
        while (column <= gridSize-1){
```

Or you could use a for loop:

```
for ( row = 0; row < gridSize; row++ ) {
    for ( column = 0; column < gridSize; column++ ) {
        ...
```

If you choose to do so, don't forget to remove the `row++` and `column++` from inside the loop body so that they are not incremented twice.

Comment: Im sorry I do not understand why all other statements aren't handled by the final else statement. because If the cell does not meet the above criteria then it jumps to the bottom of the if-else statement and either changes the value of the cell or keeps it dead

Comment: @jay why do you think it jumps magically to the bottom of the if-else statement? The `if-else` statement tests a condition. If the condition is true, it executes the first block, if not, it executes the `else` block. What would make them jump to an `else` that is not in their scope?

Comment: Okay I did what you said and now 2 points on my grid are flashing. Im guessing that I still messed something up but you are a lifesaver because I never even got it to move. Im going to edit the code above so you can see what Ive done.

Comment: @jay better add the new version as an edit after the original code, or the answers will seem unrelated to the question.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me this far! I followed your suggestions but still fail to get the correct results. Although the results aren't correct I am grateful because I am now much closer to the answer.

Comment: @jay - Just noticed another thing and added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using only one grid, you need a second grid where to put the cells next state ...

Comment: you have to use the first grid as is, apply game rules for each cell(i,j) , then store the result in the (i,j) cell of the second grid .

Comment: okay, but how would I do that? do I need to create a new variable and if so what type would it be? Im sorry im a beginner so I am new to all of this

Comment: At first , i was thinking Grid class was a structure in memory but now i realize that is a java UI component, right? if so , you should do calculation using a pair of memory structure let say 2 bidimension array like int[][] grid1 = new int[200][200]; int[][] grid2 = new int[200][200]; then copy the value to the Grid UI

Comment: Im sorry we havent learned that yet. Here is a link to my instructions http://cobweb.cs.uga.edu/~cs1301/files/Lab07.pdf